What Java and Groovy configuration steps are needed to run repast simphony batch runs directly from the command line?
I am attempting to launch batch runs for Repast Simphony on Windows without having to start the runs from within the GUI. I am able to produce the configuration properties file from within the GUI - I just want to actually start the runs from the command line, as the Repast documentation discusses.
I am experiencing a Java error as shown below when I run the command to perform batch runs. I have already confirmed that batch runs started within the batch-run GUI work successfully, so the issue appears to be something to do with how I am trying to do the runs from the command line.
Per section 9.2.1 of https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf, I saved a batch-configuration file from the batch-run GUI and placed that in the same directory as my batch_runner.jar file. I then went to run a command like java -jar batch_runner.jar -hl -r -c sample_batch_configuration.properties command from my Bash terminal on my Windows machine. Because I have a different java version as my default java (JAVA_HOME env variable), in this case I actually am directly calling the JDK-11 that I use within Repast Simphony for the batch-run GUI, by using the following command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\lib\java.exe" -jar batch_runner.jar -hl -r -c batch_configuration.properties. It results in the error below, suggesting that something isn't quite right with my Java / Groovy setup.
INFO  10:15:24,983 repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain - Writing batch run config file to: <my_repast_directory>\output\config.props
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at repast.simphony.batch.standalone.StandAloneMain.run(StandAloneMain.java:207)
        at repast.simphony.batch.standalone.StandAloneMain.main(StandAloneMain.java:276)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.createAntProject(HeadlessMain.java:87)
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.run(HeadlessMain.java:66)
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.main(HeadlessMain.java:310)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 9 more

Is some additional step needed to link Java to the required Groovy capabilities when I am outside of Eclipse and trying to perform batch runs with repast simphony?

we are tracking this issue here: https://github.com/Repast/repast.simphony/issues/96. That includes an updated batch_runner.jar that could try.
